# Same defaults data show in CoreData with iCloud

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, icloud

When the app launched at fitst time, I insert one default data into coredata database. After that, when installing the app to another device with same Apple ID, the other default data insertion occurs. As a result, there are 2 default data.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any code that checks to see if the defaults already exist before you insert them?

Comment: I need default category data. So, I write the insertion code which will run at the first launch. The problem is that data doesn't come when the app launches..